# Login module will not display in IE 8 Joomla 2.5

Tags: css, joomla, internet-explorer-8, joomla2.5

I currently am using the Login Styles for Joomla module as the login module for a Joomla 2.5.9 site with the JS Elated template. This module displays a drop down box for logging in when a user clicks the login image.

In every browser but Internet Explorer 8, the login module will display with no problems. However, in IE 8, the Login module's button image will not appear, but the module will still be there.

By talking to the module's support team, I learned that the file causing this problem was the file ie.css. Removing the file helped, but resulted a button in the drop down to appear too dark.

Looking at ie.css, I found the following styles:

```
button,
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"] {
behavior: url('./templates/js_elated/css/PIE.php');
background: #eee url(../images/button-light.png) repeat-x;
background: gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(1,  #ccc));
border: 1px solid #ccc;
color: #000;
}
```

Commenting out the lines defining the background or the lines that defined the color resulted in either the login image not appearing, or the image for the button labeled "Log in" appearing too dark.

What would you recommend that I do? Thank you.

Comment: A IE8 specific css/code include that just uses a lower colour background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ie up to version 8 doesn't have proper support for many CSS3 properties and functions, such as gradient and border-radius.

the library PIE.css is a very effective solution as it goes around most limitations; on occasion it will require either position:relative or zoom:1 be added.

So your code should work. But since it obviously doesn't you may:

1. fiddle with position:relative and zoom:1 and see if it's solved, or something along these lines: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/
2. drop the gradient for IE, and use the background image that's provided. You might want to write the shorthand background in a different order for this to work: despite this being correct as per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background I have to note that FF and chrome write it differently in their inspectors with color at the end
3. just use a fixed-color background, in the end if they're using IE they don't deserve pretty interfaces.